# Why do these two ways of specifying a callback for onPressed work?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to learn about why these two ways to call the same method work (and why a third does not).

In the included sample app, the `_MyHomePageState` widget has these defined:

```dart
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }
```

I notice that in the onPressed within the button, either of these will work:

```dart
onPressed: _incrementCounter,
```

OR

```dart
onPressed: ()=> _incrementCounter(),
```

But this will not work:

```dart
onPressed: _incrementCounter(),
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because both working examples are function references, whereas the option that doesn't work is *immediately calling the function*.  The first is a named function, and the second is an anonymous function that calls the named function.  Since `onPressed` is expecting a function reference, you need to pass one of your references.  If you call the function (which is what happens when you put the parenthesis after the reference name) you'll just pass the result of the function, which in your example is void.

For example, let's say we have the following:

```
int counter = 0;
void doThing() { ++counter; }
var doAnotherThing = () => doThing();
```

In this example, `doThing` and `doAnotherThing` both reference functions.  The difference between them is that `doAnotherThing` references an anonymous function, whereas doThing is a named function.  The anonymous function calls the named function.  So, if we executed the following, how many times would `doThing` be called?  What would be the value of `counter`?

```
doThing();
doAnotherThing();
```

The value would be `2`.  Note that since `doAnotherThing` is just a reference to a function, in our example you could do something like this:

```
var doAnotherThing = doThing;
```

However, if you call the function (instead of creating a reference to it) you would end up with a `void` reference:

```
var doAnotherThing = doThing(); // doThing returns void, so we get a void reference
```

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Yes that does clarify it. Thanks for the clear and thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`onPressed` property should be passed as `VoidCallback` or `void Function()`. The `void _incrementCounter() {}` type is already a `void Function()` so you don't need to give extra braces to use it as property.

The extra braces will execute the function instead passing it on the `Widget`.